# How register MetadataBuilderContributor in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hql, querydsl

Good afternoon! Who use MetadataBuilderContributor to register new function in HQL?
I work with Spring and QueryDSL.
I want to register new function to work with json through QueryDSL.

[MetadataBuilderContributor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARKRW.png)

When I use it I get exception
QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: ( near line 3, column 20 [select file\nfrom File file\nwhere json_like_any(file.body,?1,?2)];

I  think I have a problem with registration MetadataBuilderContributor

I have tried to register through
[application.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28yFn.png)

and through
[bean creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHZ0P.png)

How I use it
[with QueryDSL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbpps.png)

May be someone have another idea how to do it or what the reason of this problem?